# Due to hip and knee problems I need to fit my saddle a couple of inches further back is there a bracket available?

Tags: saddle

Due to hip and knee problems I would like to move my saddle  up to a couple of inches backward, is there a bracketed seatpost or similar available? Any solution would allow me to ride for longer periods, an answer would be very much appreciated.

Comment: You might try googling "offset seat post". "Layback seat post" also seems to be used; it might be a brand name

Comment: That's an answer.

Comment: @ojs my quick googling didn't find the couple of inches that the OP was looking for (I saw numbers like 25mm). Also I'm fairly confident this is a duplicate but on the mobile site you don't get the "related questions" list to make checking easy.

Comment: Good point. The maximum I could find was 40mm.

Comment: I just Thursday saw a sort of L-shaped post designed to accept a BSO seat and offset it backwards about 2 inches.  Apparently intended to make a child's frame more suitable for a teen, as a stunt bike.  I've no idea what you'd call it or where you'd get one, however.

Comment: Are you up for a larger replacement frame, and lower the seatpost and raise the bars ?

Comment: Also, are you sure you want the saddle backward?  That will stretch you out on the bike  and your thighs will make a sharper angle to your spine.   Is it possible you want to move the saddle forward to allow a more upright position?

Comment: @Criggie - perhaps the OP wants to raise their bars (opening hip angle) and sit back to reduce tension on knee tendons?

Comment: You might try Google for a local (or, maybe, not quite so local) frame builder (I managed to find one long before the days of Google). (S)He may be able to make and/or modify a seat post for you with the necessary offset, or possibly design something that would have some fore/aft adjustment available to it. Plus you get to support your local frame builder.

Answer (score 2):

There are offset seatpost but I don't know of any that are more than 25mm = 1 inch

[image]

Comment: In the triathlon corner of the bike-shop you might find some stuff. Triathletes do weird things with saddles

Answer (score 2):

A bit of googling turned out that there is such an adapter: http://www.vk-international.com/en/vk-producten/vk-zadelverzetter/

It works only with single vertical bolt seat posts and looks quite scary but apparently does the job.

[image: Image from linked website]

Answer (score 2):

If nothing else works, I saw this om twitter a few days ago 
[image]

[Saddle hack](https://twitter.com/JojoDegenhardt/status/849597774962315265)

Comment: OMG   The ability to reproduce is at risk and maybe that is a good thing.  Looks like they could have just rotated the offset to forward for the same effect.   +1 for the entertainment value.

Comment: This is dangerous. Bolts are designed for tensile strength, not designed to withstand bending forces. The seat post interface is not designed to withstand massively increased the torque this could produced,  The safety of the clamp interface of the saddle rails is compromised - twisting forces are acting on just one tab not two as a correctly mounted seat is.

Answer (score 1):

I know this isn't necessarily answering the question, but I feel it speaks more to the problem this person is experiencing.  Maybe instead of moving the seat back, which would be likely to cause you reach/back strain/lumbar flex issues, you should be looking at bikes with a "foot forward" geometry.  These are generally cruiser-type bikes, not sporty at all, good for neighborhood rides and bike paths.  But they are definitely easier on your back/hips/knees.  I won't name specific brands, as I've been made to believe we don't do that on this site, but there are several brands making them, and your LBS should have something in stock you can test ride just to see if it helps.